# Can the route "match 'welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'" be shortened?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have:

```
match 'welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'
```

There is only one welcome action/page which is index. So could I just have

```
match 'welcome/' => 'welcome#index'
```

(Assuming no other welcome/ directories exist anywhere) or one of these:

```
match 'welcome' => 'welcome#index'

match '/welcome' => 'welcome#index'

match '/welcome/' => 'welcome#index'
```

Is match working like some kinda regexp and can I have the slahes in to make sure if looks for stuff that's a directory?

Comment: I cannot run the server right now + I am looking for Best Practice also

Answer (score 1):

This would work fine for you :

```
match '/welcome' => 'welcome#index'
```

And "/welcome" represents the pathname that you would have for some controller's action. It has nothing to do with any welcome directory.

so for example if you want the link to the welcome#index to be localhost:3000/imhere

```
match '/imhere' => 'welcome#index'
```